# Allow users of my web app to post to their personal facebook page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api, omniauth-facebook

I have read a lot about allowing users to log into my rails app via facebook omniauth, though I would like users, having loggeed in, to be able to post a to their own personal wall by simply clicking a button in my app. Is this possible? I'm not very new to rails but have never integrated facebook functionality and am very new to working with omniauth. I'm not looking for someone to spell out the specifics...just point me in the right direction! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Facebook documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.2/user/feed) and [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#publishing), publishing a post to user's wall on behalf of the subject user is not allowed. Instead of this, they encourage the sharing ability.

I hope this is helpful.